# Solve $\frac{a^2}{x^2 f'(x)}-\log{{(1-f(x))}}=S^2 +1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Solve
>   $$  \frac{a^2}{x^2 f'(x)}-\log{{(1-f(x))}}=S^2 +1,  $$ for $x\geq 1$, $f(x)<1$
>   where $a,S\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f'(x)=\frac{d f(x)}{dx}$.

**My effort:** It is equivalent to 
$$  {a^2}-(x^2 f'(x))\log{{(1-f(x))}}-(S^2 +1)(x^2 f'(x))=0,  $$
or
$$  {a^2}- f'(x)x^2(\log{{(1-f(x))}}-S^2 +1)=0,  $$

I am not sure what to do with the $\log(1-f(x))$. Any idea?

Comment: This is a [separable differential equation](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/sepble/sepble.html).  You solve it by writing it as
$(\log(1-f)+(S^2+1))\; df = a^2/x^2\; dx$ and integrating both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make life easier, first let $$\log(1-f)= y \implies f=1-e^{y}\implies f'=e^y \,y'$$ making the equation to be
$$\frac{a^2 e^{-y}}{x^2 y'}+y+S^2+1=0$$ which is, as Robert Israel commented, is separable.
$$\frac{a^2}{x^2}=-(y+S^2+1)\,e^y\,y'$$ Integrate both sides
$$\frac {a^2}x+C=e^y \left(S^2+y\right)$$ If you want to go further to get $y$, let $z=S^2+y$ to make$$e^{S^2}\left(\frac {a^2}x+C\right)=z \,e^z$$ which has a solution
$$z=W\left(\frac{e^{S^2} \left(a^2+C x\right)}{x}\right)$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Now, go back to $y$ and then to $f$ for an analytical expression.

Comment: Perfect !! Just one question, i'm currently learning about this function, is there no function in closed form $W(x)$ ? I guess not, else it would have been mentioned somewhere.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi. No, this is a special and very beautiful function. If you search on this site *Lambert function* , you will find 2276 posts related to it.

Comment: Wow you're right .. Looks like i got to find out why .. thanks for the info !!

Comment: @AhmadBazzi. You are very welcome ! Glad to help. By the way, it is worth to spend time learning about this function. There are many uses of it in almost all areas (in mathematics, physics, even chemistry).

Comment: Yes I will .. Do you know of any usage of this function in statistics ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi. I am very bad in statistics (as in many other areas). Just as a first key, try to remember that any equation which can write as $a+b x+c\log(d+ex)=0$ has solution(s) in terms of Lambert function.

Comment: Thanks for all the rich info !!